# Can not boot with ubuntu. No grub no boot option can't boot repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows

Update after answer=> How can i be sure that i install ubuntu on uefi mode?

I am a total noob about Linux systems. So that's my problem.

I installed windows with ubuntu to my laptop according to this tutorial => [Tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)

I formatted all drives first. Then I installed windows. After that, I switched my bios setting to legacy mode. And installed ubuntu.

So that's the problem. I can not boot to Ubuntu. My laptop directly goes to the windows.

List of what I tried so far:

1. tried this at windows : bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
2. tried to use boot repair but failed. Because when I created a bootable boot repair flash disk I cannot boot it if legacy mode is off. And boot repair refuses to work on legacy mode.
3. Tried to boot to ubuntu flash disk (I think it is called preview as I said before I am a total noob) and I tried to run the boot repair at that state. But like I mentioned at list item 2 I can only boot to that state on legacy mode and boot repair is not working at legacy mode.
4. I switched off the fast start and hibernate from windows. Secure boot is also off.

I tried all that but nothing changed. I have a installed ubuntu on my laptop which I can not reach. I can reach to bootable flash disks only in legacy mode but nothing else. Please help. I searched through questions but couldn't find a similar question. There is a lot of "can't boot" questions but that solutions didn't work for me.

P.S: Ubuntu version 18.04.1

Thanks.

Comment: If Windows is installed in UEFI mode, Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI mode too. And vise versa ... both OSs must be installed in same mode, to make dualboot work.

Comment: Oh then i think i should install ubuntu again for make this correct? If it doesn't shows when legacy mode off then i think i installed ubuntu in bios mode? Thank you @SorenA btw

Comment: If drive is gpt partitioned, you can just reinstall grub, not entire system. But you need to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode and often easier for new users to just use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. May need to use Boot-Repair's advanced options.

Comment: @oldfred As i mentioned in the post I could not boot to boot-repair flash without legacy mode on. And it does not work on legacy mode:) I think I'll try to reinstall. But thank you

Comment: To install in UEFI mode you have to boot in UEFI mode, for both Windows & Ubuntu installs or repairs. You may need to turn on UEFI boot in UEFI and also turn on allow USB boot. In legacy mode it may allow the USB boot automatically.